# Burninate the [easter-eggs] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

An easter egg in some software is not a problem to be fixed. Asking what [easter-eggs](/questions/tagged/easter-eggs) there are is a polling question, and unanswerable in many cases. Fortunately, not a common tag, but every question I've seen with it was off topic. I recommend burninating and black listing it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the tag is nothing but a collection of off-topic questions.

I see several valid uses of the tag when I look at the questions tagged with it. Burninating and blacklisting it sounds overkill to me.